# graphics - how to change the position of only one caption in beamer

Tags: beamer, captions

I want to change the position of the caption of *only one* figure in my beamer presentation. I want it to be positioned at the right of the image, vertically centered.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,labelfont=footnotesize, justification=centering, belowskip=-10pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{images/someimage.png}
    \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify in which way you'd like to change the position? Do you want the caption on top? Or left/right aligned? Something else? Please also add a short, but compilable test document so we can see if you use beamer's own caption mechanism or a 3rd party package.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sorry, I just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using the caption package, you could use the `\captionof` macro and place the caption and your image in adjacent columns:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,labelfont=footnotesize, justification=centering, belowskip=-10pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
  \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \end{column}    
  \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption}
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]